# Why can't conductors be used in making ICs (integrated circuits) instead of semiconductors?

Tags: semiconductors, vlsi, conductivity, conductors, resistivity

I really wanted to ask why we can not control flow of electrons in conductors.

Can I not say if a current is flowing in a conductor it is 1 and when I disconnect the supply it is 0.

Can you elaborate on this point?
Can you elaborate by taking example?

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopaedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've already done as much as you possibly could - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. This is one line expecting a huge effort from people in return. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your own work and own findings in considerable detail. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract. Again, welcome.

Comment: How will you implement, say a simple controlled switch (similar to a properly biased transistor)  with a conductor only? Remember, mechanical stuff is pretty hard to push into IC, so relays are not an option.

Comment: More in line with the body of your question than the title, [relay computers](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/relay_computer) are viable, but you can see an IC built with them would be the size of a filing cabinet.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Filing cabinet? I think it is a *very* humble approximation.

Comment: Conductors are used inside integrated circuits to connect logic elements. These conducting **metals** are meant to connect with low losses, and it is very difficult to dissuade conduction - they have very low resistance. On the other hand, logic elements are made with **semiconductors**, which can be influenced to either conduct or not to conduct.

Comment: @EugeneSh. [Here](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~harry/Relay/) is a real relay computer (nearby me.) Size is now concretely clear. ;)

Comment: @jonk Yeah, but if we speak of something comparable to even some ancient 386, I think it will be way larger, if possible at all.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh, sure. Who mentioned an 80386, though? I must have missed it.

Comment: All you need to do, in order to control the current in a copper conductor for example, is to control the placement and gradation of electric charges along the conductor's surface. Solve that problem and current control is at hand.

Comment: @jonk No one, just to have apples to apples comparison

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not exactly sure how it may be possible to have apples to apples comparisons with relays vs fabbed CMOS. But perhaps a 6502 might be closer to Porter's relay computer if a comparison is to be had. Yet the relays are far, far slower. So it's still not an apples to apples comparison. Not sure how that would be possible in a bright line, no arguments from anyone, way.

Answer (score 2):

> I really wanted to ask why we can not control flow of electrons in conductors.

You could control the flow of charge in a conductor if you can change its resistance. There are two simple ways to do this:

1. Change its diameter or length. Reducing diameter or increasing length will increase resistance.
2. Change its temperature. Metals have a positive temperature coefficient of resistance.

As you can see neither of these is practical at any kind of speed and neither gives you a zero current for a logic zero.

> Can I not say if a current is flowing in a conductor it is 1 and when I disconnect the supply it is 0.

You can say whatever you like but unless you can control the current you won't be able to make a logic switch.

Semiconductors are used because their conductivity is easily controlled over many orders of magnitude. Their conductivity is controlled by a relatively small signal. Semiconductors allow for amplification.

Answer (score 1):

Semiconductor diodes can rectify current and transistors may be linear amplifiers by using a small modulation to create a large output swing  of the output voltage or  output current limited by resistance.

They may also be used as switches with limits on voltage and current output.

Conductors may be used as switches may not be used to amplify.  Relays can be magnetically moved to operate conductive contacts.

“Semi” implies that depending on bias current or voltage on input the output can act like an insulator or a conductor but with polarized constraints.